# scrartcl toc sectionentrywithdots formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, scrartcl, dotfill

Im pretty new to tex. I managed to get everything I wanted.
But I am stuck with the table of contents.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,toc=sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}
```

Now I would like the section dots to be printed boldly as well as the heading in the table of contents.
Is there a way to do this without destroying the entire formatting?

[image: toc with same dots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not recommend the bold dots in TOC.

If you really want bold dots for the section entries, use

```latex
\addtokomafont{sectionentrydots}{\bfseries}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,toc=sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\addtokomafont{sectionentrydots}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. You can replace fill characters completely.
Sectionentrywithdots is not needed for this.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
```

And with this you can then use the desired character. `\textbf{.}` is then the bold dot here.

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  toclinefill={\TOCLineLeaderFill[\textbf{.}]}
]{section}
```